# Aptana not saving changes

Tags: aptana

I have installed Aptana onto my new laptop the same way as I have installed it on all my computers.  When I make changes to a file in my project, those changes are not getting written to the local file itself (confirmed this by opening the file in another program like notepad).  However, if I re-open the file in Aptana (even if i restart the computer), I can still see the changes that I have made to that file.

I have never seen Aptana do this before.  On all my other computers, this does not happen.  Usually I just open the file in my project, save my changes and the changes are saved instantly ready for me to FTP the file.

At first I thought it was a permission issue as I was unable to save the file even when opening in notepad.  I updated the folder permissions but this still has not resolved anything.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

Comment: I am having the same issue.. Did you manage to get anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I experienced this.

1. If I created a new project with an existing .git, then no changes were written to the files git was managing in the original directory.
2. If I created a new project from a folder (no git), and no changes were written to that original directory.

As a general rule, Aptana will copy the contents of your files over to the "project directory" it is using (default on my machine was ~/Documents/Aptana.../ProjectName).

So, you either have to make the project-directory the parent dir of where you keep your files, or you have to start using the project-dir/ProjectName directory as your working folder.

You can also do "file->export->General->FileSystem" whenever you want to copy the files to another local dir.