# Laravel NotFoundHttpException (RouteCollection->match)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am new to Laravel and was following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zz_R73eW3OU&list=PL09BB956FCFB5C5FD). I have just installed the latest version of Laravel and am going through the beginning stages of the tutorial. So far (installation, creating a migration) I was doing ok, but now I am stuck at the point of creating new routes.

I have created a controller in app/controllers:

```
<?php

class Slots_Controller extends Base_Controller{

    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index(){
        return View::make( 'slots.index' );
    }

}
```

As well as a very minimalist view in the file app/views/slots/index.php

```
<h1>Slots</h1>
```

My app/routes file looks like this :

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get( '/public/slots', array(
    'uses' => 'slots@index'
) );
```

I've searched a number of things on the web and here is how far I have come :
- i know ideally only the public dir should be in the htdocs, i will be doing that presumably at a further stage of the tutorial. so as of now, my laravel home page is at `http://localhost:8888/my_directory.laravel/public/`
- i have checked the apache mod-rewrite : it is on and it works well for codeIgniter
- i have checked that the .htaccess is as provided by laravel (and as suggested by different posts)

The weird thing is, if i change the routes for the home page like this :

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return 'hello world';
//  return View::make('hello');
});
```

Nothing changes, i.e. i still get the original welcome page. My understanding is this modification should have simply output "hello world" as the html for the home page.

So it seems that whatever I'm doing in routes.php has no effect whatsoever, as if I was modifying the wrong file or something.

I've spent the most part of an otherwise sunny afternoon on this, any help is much apreciated :)

Thanks,

Tepp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things you are doing wrong here (The best way is to follow the tutorial on [Laravel](http://laravel.com)):

1. In your controller file you are mentioning "Base_Controller", are you sure you have such a file in your controllers directory? (According to my knowledge it should be BaseController)
2. The Route::get is not defined properly. There are many ways to define a route; however for your case it should be something like this:

   Route::get('slots', array(
      'uses' => 'Slots_Controller@get_index'
   ));

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
1. You are absolutely right about BaseController, I overlooked that, I have corrected it
2. I have also applied the new line for route, but this doesn't seem to solve my problem.
In fact, as of now, my routes file only contains Route::get('/', function() return 'hello world';});
that is in order to see if this changes anything when going to the home page, but it doesn't :(

Comment: I would ask you to lookup for the tutorial on Laravel. Your route is perfectly fine (as mentioned in the question; in the comment above you are missing an opening bracket). However, I think you might have  missed some other part. There is nothing wrong with your route.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I had actually been following a bit of both tutorials but i just went back to the laravel doc and have been checking the steps, so far so good. When reading about the lifecycle of a request (http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle), i had the idea to just try to echo a string at different parts of the process to see how far i got. well, this is what's intriguing : i can't seem to change anything, whatever i do ! even changing the app/views/hello.php file which is shown on the welcome page does not do anything.

Comment: i am at a loss here : the only file containing the word "arrived" in my laravel folder (so the only file which could output "You have arrived" on the welcome screen) is in fact that hello.php view but if i try to output "You have not arrived" for example it doesn't change a thing. i tried clearing the cache / using a different browser, to no avail. i believe i am doing a very basic mistake in some part of my installation/configuration here but for the life of me i can't understand what's going on. i'll continue reading the tutorial in the meantime...

Comment: ok i think i might be having a serious issue with my ide, i'll be back in a minute as soon as i understand what's going on !

Comment: I would suggest you to just start a fresh project. You might have messed up a few things here.

Comment: found my answer here, i was just not modifying the files in my htdocs... frustrating (and stupid i admit) !! : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133137/aptana-not-saving-changes/23658656#23658656

Comment: so i'm back on track now and will let you know how things go, my new "slots" route is not working yet but at least i can start following what's going on :)

Comment: Ok, there appears to have been a little bit of a syntax thing going on also. The tutorial I used was for a previous version so to revert things I had to change the names of some files / classes / methods : controller file is now called `SlotsController.php` and the prototype is `class SlotsController extends BaseController`, its method is `index`. As for the route, it now points to `array( 'uses' => 'SlotsController@index' )` ... Thanks for the help !